# Error : 'cryptography' package is required for sha256_password or caching_sha2_password auth methods

Tags: python, django, pymysql

I try to connect to my admin page of my django site which is online, but I get the error that I put on the title, and yet the connection passed yesterday,
I tried to install the package with :

```
$ python3 -m pip install PyMySQL[rsa]
```

and I have the answer:

```
Requirement already satisfied
```

hecked the connection with the database there is no error at this level

Comment: try to install `cryptography` via `pip install cryptography`?

Comment: I also do: $pip install cryptography
and I have Requirement already satisfied

Comment: try with pip3 maybe and provide more info about your environments. The output of `pip3 freeze` and `pip freeze` might help.

Comment: I answered you by re-editing my post.

Comment: I restarted my apache2 and it worked. ,

Comment: the latest version is https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/ 39.0.0 tho, try uninstall and install with `pip3 install cryptography=39.0.0`